# Ubuntu 18.04.5 - Static noise on headphones when playing audio/video after installation of linux-image-5.4.0-70-generic

Tags: sound, kernel, pulseaudio, alsa

After I started up my notebook today, the unattended upgrade installed linux-image-5.4.0-70-generic (I was using 5.4.0.67 until yesterday), and I started noticing a static noise on my P2 headphones whenever I play a video or music.

I'm sure this issue wasn't present until yesterday, because I spent the day watching class videos and I didn't notice anything.

I have obviously tried using other headphones, and I also have already tried running `pulseaudio -k` and changing `alsamixer` configurations.

EDIT: Tried booting on previous kernel version (5.4.0.67), but the problem remained.

Has anyone noticed something similar?

`Card: HDA Intel PCH` and `Chip: Realtek ALC255`

`Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, Release: 18.04`

Comment: which release? `lsb_release -rd`

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, Release: 18.04